# Write arraylist to text file C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a method that reads a text file and writes the contents to an array list. The array list is declared globally with no elements. This method works perfectly.

```
private void LoadArrayList()
{
    try
    {
        string actor;
        TextReader tr;
        tr = File.OpenText("actors.txt");

        while ((actor = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ActorArrayList.Add(actor);
        }
        tr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading file!");
    }
}
```

I now need to create a method that reads the array list and writes the contents back to the text file, replacing what is currently in the text file. This method results in a blank text file. Any idea's what I am missing/doing wrong?

```
private void WriteArrayList()
{
    TextWriter tw;

    try
    {
        tw = File.CreateText("actors.txt");
        foreach (object o in ActorArrayList)
            tw.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving file!");
    }
}
```

NOTE: I know people don't seem to like array lists or TextReader or TextWriter, but the course I am doing covers them so I am required to use them.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `ArrayList`, you usually only use that for backwards compatibility, it is generally preferable to use `List<T>`, in this case a `List<string>`.

Comment: You need to use `using` blocks when you handle classes implementing `IDisposable`. If you have a Visual Studio that supports it, turn on static code analysis so you will get a warning when you forget it.

Comment: Use `tw.Close();` at the end of your method.

Comment: @Ben Robinson  I am using ArrayList because that is what my course requires me to do. Whether I move onto using List next I am not sure.

Comment: @nvoigt I will turn it on, thanks. I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Flush or Close your writer:

```
private void WriteArrayList()
{
    TextWriter tw = null;

    try
    {
        tw = File.CreateText("actors.txt");
        foreach (object o in ActorArrayList)
            tw.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving file!");
    }
    finally
    {
        if(tw != null)
            tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Now that's an answer! :)

Comment: I added a Close, using the finally block it gives me an error "Use of an unassigned local variable 'tw'". But if I place it directly after tw.WriteLine(o.ToString()); it works fine.

Comment: @mrkd1991: I edited the answer to solve this issue. good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can manage to do this in a 1 liner using linq `Cast()`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"actors.txt", ActorArrayList.Cast<string>());
```

Alternatively, the below logic should work out

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"actors.txt"))
{
    foreach (string actor in ActorArrayList)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(actor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a call to tw.Flush() and also a call to tw.Close(). Without calling these the content may not actually get written to disk but only persists in memory.
Also in this case you should alwas use a using block as mentioned before.

See this example:

```
using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText("actors.txt"))
{
   try
   {
      foreach (object o in ActorArrayList)
         tw.WriteLine(o.ToString());
      tw.Flush();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBoxShow("Error saving file!");
   }
}
```